# Updating Connected sortable Lists with Mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I'm working off some tutorials. I have been looking around for quite a while and cant seem to hit the nail on the head. Here is my code so far.

Index

```
<?php       
$result = mysql_query("SELECT MAX(listid) AS listid FROM testtable");  
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))  
{    
for ($i=1; $i<=(int)$row['listid']; $i++) {?>
<div class="heading" >List <?php echo $i; ?></div>
<ul class="connectedSortable sortable">
  <?php
$item = "SELECT * FROM testtable WHERE listid='".$i."' ORDER BY posid ASC";
$list = mysql_query($item); $x = 1; 
while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($list, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
    ?>
  <li class="ui-state-default" id="recordsArray_<?php echo $row2['linkid']; ?>">
  <?php echo $row2['linkname']; ?></li>
  <?php $x++;
}
?>
</ul>
<?php 
}} 
?>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(function () {
      $(".sortable").sortable({
          connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
          distance: 5,
          zIndex: 0,
          opacity: 0.6,
          cursor: 'move',
          update: function() {
            var order = $(this).sortable("serialize")
+ '&action=updateRecordsListings'; 
            $.post("updateDB.php", order)}
      }).disableSelection();
  });
});
```

and the updateDB.php code

```
    <?php 
require("connect2.php");

$action = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['action']); 
$updateRecordsArray = $_POST['recordsArray'];

if ($action == "updateRecordsListings"){

    $posidCounter = 1;
    foreach ($updateRecordsArray as $recordIDValue) {

        $query = "UPDATE testtable SET posid = ".$posidCounter."
        WHERE linkid=".$recordIDValue;
        mysql_query($query) or die('Error, insert query failed');
        $posidCounter = $posidCounter + 1;  
    }
}
?>
```

Now everything seems to work fine.  But what I'm trying to achieve is when I move a list item to a connected List, update the database to reflect that items position in the new list. at the moment it is only updating its position within its originating list.

I'm very new to all this, so any help would be grand! Thanks in advance.

My table looks something like this:

```
+----------+----------+---------+--------+
| linkname |  linkid  |  posid  | listid |
+----------+----------+---------+--------+
|     1    |     1    |    2    |    1   |
|     1    |     2    |    1    |    1   |
|     1    |     3    |    1    |    2   | 
|     1    |     4    |    2    |    2   |
+----------+----------+---------+--------+
```

Comment: These tutorials are a little out-of-date.

Comment: So there is a better way to achieve this then?