# create a 2d array of sortable lists

Tags: jquery, arrays, jquery-ui-sortable

I posted a question previously [See Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18555981/updating-connected-sortable-lists-with-mysql) and nearly have a solution that I would like to post.

I have managed to get this working by using the following:

```
$(".todoList").sortable({
    update: function (event, ui) {
        if (this === ui.item.parent()[0]) {
            var numLists = $("ul.menu").length;
            for (var i = 1; i <= numLists; i++) {
                $.post("updateDB.php", {
                    pages: $("#menu-pages" + i).sortable('toArray'),
                    listid: i
                });
            }
        }
    },
    connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
});
```

However, with this solution it will query the DB x amount of times if I have x amount of lists. Before I post the answer, I want to know if it would be possible to create a 2D array of the arrays for each 'i' and only $.post once.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you well, you could try something like this:

```
$(".todoList").sortable({
    update: function (event, ui) {
        if (this === ui.item.parent()[0]) {
            var numLists = $("ul.menu").length;
            var pages = [];
            for (var i = 1; i <= numLists; i++) {
                //here is the edit
                pages.push($("#menu-pages" + i).sortable('toArray'));
            }
            $.post("updateDB.php", {
                pages: pages
            });
        }
    },
    connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
});
```

Now you need to change your `updateDB.php` since the parameters that are getting passed with this version of the code are not the same as before.

Comment: Thanks for the reply e. I made a fiddle to test this and cant seem to echo anything from the array out. says its undefined. [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/nBGsT/1/). Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @banjo: hey man I'm sorry, my bad. I confused the javascipt arrays `push` method with the jQuery `append` method, I've been using the last one a lot lately ;). Check the answer now, it works for sure.